# Windows: directly switch to a specific application instead of tabbing through using alt+tab

Tags: windows-10, productivity

I normally use a limited amount of applications like Chrome, Android Studio, Word etc. Instead of switching between them using alt+tab and cycling through them, I want to directly jump to them, e.g. ctrl+alt+c for Chrome, ctrl+alt+a for Android Studio etc. Is there any built-in Windows functionality or any tool that can do that for me?

Comment: The application is underlined on the task bar. You can directly click it there without using Alt-Tab. I use this frequently.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I don't understand. Can you give more details? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest arrange the applications in the task tray as you prefer and then use Windows Key+1, Windows Key+2, etc..

Comment: If you set a shortcut key in a shortcut file in the start menu or desktop, that shortcut key will open the target file if it hasn't already been opened or switch to it if it has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open programs, they appear in your taskbar. You can click on the program to switch to them.

Given that you mention Alt-Tab, I reckon you are actually looking for a keyboard shortcut, even though you don't specify that you are looking for it.

Luckily windows does provide shortcut keys.

You can switch to the first 9 programs that appear in your taskbar by pressing <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>...<kbd>9</kbd>

By pinning the apps you want to use frequently to the taskbar and place them at the desired location, you can make opening and switching to them a matter of just pressing that keycombination.

For example, if you put Chrome pinned on the first position, next to the start menu button, you can now always press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to open Chrome or to switch to it if its not active.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 underlines an active application on the Task Bar. You can directly click it there without using Alt-Tab. I use this feature very frequently for the same reason as you.  I provided a screen shot and amplified the underline.  Check on your system and you will see it there. I am assuming a version of Windows 10 in support.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of switching between them using alt+tab and cycling through them

When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to see all your running apps, there's actually now a way to jump directly to the one you want.

In older versions of Windows, you had to cycle through the apps until the one you wanted was selected. But under Windows 10 you can now just click the app you want.